# Rails 4.0: ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I'm starting serven in production mode, i got this page:

```
"The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."
```

App works normally in development mode.

Here is my logs:

```
I, [2013-04-22T11:27:17.618777 #15685]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 11:27:17 +0400
F, [2013-04-22T11:27:17.620365 #15685] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0.beta1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0.beta1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0.beta1) lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/u164/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/u164/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/u164/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

My Gemfile:

```
ruby "1.9.3"
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'
```

Comment: can you list your routes file contents here pls?

Comment: Do you have a static index page displayed when you hit "/" in the development mode?

Comment: ty, I thought rails 4 generates index page automatically.

Comment: It does generate the index page automatically, but if there is an index page in the public dir, that will be loaded instead of the one generated by rails.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4.0.0 when deploying to production, you will need to generate/create an index page which should be located in public/index.html.

I have successfully deployed on Amazon EC2 (AWS) using this fix.

For example:

```
$ rails generate controller welcome index
```